# brave baggage when using scheduler and kafka raises outOfMemoryError

Tags: java, spring, out-of-memory, apache-kafka-streams

Vsem privet. V svoyem prilozheniye ya ispol'zuyu kafka stream i standartnyy scheduler postavlyayemyy spring. Pri rabote Scheduller otpravlyayutsya soobshcheniya v kafku a potom vychityvayutsya ot tuda. Pri analize dampa kuchi uvidel chto kopiyatsya dannyye iz brave baggage. Ne mogu ponyat' kak eto proiskhodit i chto nado ispravlyat'.
Hi all. In my application, I use kafka stream and the standard scheduler supplied by spring. When Scheduller runs, messages are sent to kafka and then read from there. When analyzing the heap dump, I saw that the data from brave baggage is being copied. I can't figure out how this is happening or what needs to be fixed.

[image: 1]

```
  kafka:
    streams.binder.serdeError: sendToDlq
    binder:
      brokers: localhost:9092
      auto-create-topics: true
      auto-add-partitions: true
    admin:
      fail-fast: true
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        merchant:
          destination: *******
        legal:
          destination: *******
        account:
          destination: *******
        merchant_session:
          destination: *******
        #async-task
        in-queue:
          destination: *********
          contentType: application/json
          group: merchant
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
            partitioned: true
            concurrency: 10
        in-queue-dlq:
          destination: **********
          contentType: application/json
          group: merchant
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
            back-off-initial-interval: 5000
        out-queue:
          destination: **********
          contentType: application/json
        out-queue-dlq:
          destination: **********
          contentType: application/json
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-add-partitions: true
          auto-create-topics: true
```

this is the code that is used in Scheduler
` @Transactional
@Scheduled(
cron = "${task-processor.cronExpression:*/5 * * * * ?}"
)
public void rescheduleTask() {
Integer taskRetrySize = this.properties.getTaskRetrySize();
List list = this.databaseDataProvider.findPlannedTasks(taskRetrySize);
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
log.debug("Rescheduling planned tasks. Found {} tasks for rescheduling.", list.size());
}

```
    IMessageQueueDataProvider var10001 = this.messageQueueDataProvider;
    Objects.requireNonNull(var10001);
    list.forEach(var10001::resendRequest);
}`
```

if you turn off the Scheduler, then the heap is not filled.
also in the logs there are constantly messages from kafka:

```
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-5 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-8 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-2 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-9 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-1 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-4 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-6 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-7 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.090 [pool-21-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.execute-3 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to X41sXMr6TqStCZ5BV-8Lhg
2023-02-27 22:13:25.096 [pool-22-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata
                Metadata.updateLatestMetadata(...) (Metadata.java:401) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-merchant-14, groupId=merchant] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition rdbo.merchant.task.error-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to _E_0g0iZRGeBSq0PWrpGtQ
2023-02-27 22:13:25.101 [pool-22-thread-1] [- | -] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator
```

these logs disappear if you turn off prometheus

Comment: What's "brave baggage"?

Comment: spring.-cloud-sleuth and io.zipkin.brave used for tracing logs in SpringBoot application